# Are there any benefits in using non-async actions in Play Framework 2.2?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

The [Play 2.2 documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaAsync) states that:

> Because of the way Play works, the action code must be as fast as possible (ie. non blocking). So what should we return as result if we are not yet able to generate it? The response is a future result!
>
> A Future[Result] will eventually be redeemed with a value of type Result. By giving a Future[Result] instead of a normal Result, we are able to quickly generate the result without blocking. Then, Play will serve this result as soon as the promise is redeemed.
>
> The web client will be blocked while waiting for the response, but nothing will be blocked on the server, and server resources can be used to serve other clients.

Actions that return a Future are created `Action.async`, as opposed to `Action.apply` for normal, non-async actions.

Is there any benefit on having non-async Actions? It strikes me that the best way to ensure that none of my Actions are going to block is to declare all of them using `Action.async`.

In fact, according to the [Play Framework 2.3 documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAsync) it looks like in Play 2.3 all actions are async:

> Note: Both Action.apply and Action.async create Action objects that are handled internally in the same way. There is a single kind of Action, which is asynchronous, and not two kinds (a synchronous one and an asynchronous one). The .async builder is just a facility to simplify creating actions based on APIs that return a Future, which makes it easier to write non-blocking code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just because you might use `Action.async`, doesn't automatically mean you're not blocking. It all depends on whether you're using blocking API or not.

Play 2.2 seems to work the same way as Play 2.3 in this manner. There isn't really a difference between `Action.apply` and `Action.async`, other than their signatures. `Action.async` expects some block of code that returns a `Future[Result]`, while `Action.apply` expects a block of code that returns a `Result`. `Action.apply` converts that `block: => Result` into `Future[Result]` by simply calling `Future.successful(block)`. (There is a little more work that goes on before calling `Future.successful`, but this is the gist of it.)

So the use cases for each boil down to the API you're using. For example JDBC vs [ScalikeJDBC-async](https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc-async), blocking vs. non-blocking database APIs. Let's say you're fetching a user from the database and sending it back to the client as json.

The signature of a typical JDBC-backed function might look like this (ignoring failures to simplify):

```
def read(id: Long): User
```

Your controller function might then look like this:

```
def read(id: Long) = Action {
    Ok(Json.toJson(User.read(id))
}
```

This is roughly equivalent to what `Action.apply` does:

```
def read(id: Long) = Action.async {
    Future.successful(Ok(Json.toJson(User.read(id)))
}
```

`User.read` is still a blocking JDBC call, however, so this is no better than before.

Now let's say we're using an asynchronous DB call that looks something like this:

```
def read(id: Long): Future[User]
```

The controller function would look something like this:

```
def read(id: Long) = Action.async {
    User.read(id).map(user => Ok(Json.toJson(user)))
}
```

Think of it as more of a helper for using APIs that return `Future`s. The real benefits come from actual asynchronous implementations of those APIs. If you're stuck with blocking API (probably JDBC), there are other ways to manage that as well. This thread on the Play mailing list is a good read on the subject: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/WWQ0HeLDOjg

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. The link you provide is awesome, as well as the youtube video linked there [Optimizing Play for Production](http://youtu.be/cnPPLpIk9mo)

Comment: I was the contributor that wrote the text quoted in the question. I'd like to clarify that this text doesn't refer to new behavior introduced in version 2.3. The updated documentation happened to be released with Play 2.3, and was not backported to the previous branches, but it applies to version 2.x as well. See [#2187](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/2187) and [this forum message](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/yzwBa2afFcs).