# Is ActionFunction Asynchronous by default in Play Framework 2.3.x?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework-2.0

Reading the [play documentation for scala](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAsync) they say that Actions are asynchronous by default. It is the same when you compose actions with ActionFunction and derivatives like ActionBuilder ?

I mean when you do something like this:

```
class AuthenticatedDbRequest[A](val user: User,
                                val conn: Connection,
                                request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

object Authenticated extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedDbRequest] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AuthenticatedDbRequest[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    AuthenticatedBuilder(req => getUserFromRequest(req)).authenticate(request, { authRequest: AuthenticatedRequest[A, User] =>
      DB.withConnection { conn =>
        block(new AuthenticatedDbRequest[A](authRequest.user, conn, request))
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Where the block could potentially block for a long time, is invokeBlock executed asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The `invokeBlock` method of `ActionFunction` returns a `Future[Result]`. **All** Play requests are handled asynchronously.

Of course, just because all the requests are handled asynchronously, doesn't mean all is well with your application if several requests have long-running computations. That is, requests running blocking operations don't block the whole server, but they do block the thread that's handling the request. Enough of those and you'll run out of request handling threads, which will make new requests wait until the others are served.

[Further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997418/are-there-any-benefits-in-using-non-async-actions-in-play-framework-2-2/24004444#24004444) [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540544/play-framework-async-vs-sync-performance).

Comment: thanks for the answer and recommendation, the further reading is very interesting especially the thread on Play mailing list. My requirements aren't too high, so for now I'm going to keep it simple but I'll have it in mind.

Comment: It's not so much that invokeBlock is executed asynchronously (technically it is synchronously executed by the action builder, asynchronously after the body is consumed), it's that invokeBlock can dispatch perform asynchronous operations, capturing the completion of them asynchronously in a future. If you want to perform an expensive operation, wrap it in a future with an appropriate execution context, this will asynchronously dispatch it to that execution context.