# Play Action Async wrapping a Future

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework-2.0

Let's say I have an Action Async block as below in one of my controller:

```
def myCntr = Action.async { implicit request =>
  // Step 1. .... // look up over the network
  // Step 2. .... // do a database call
}
```

What would it mean to wrap Step 1 and Step 2 in a Future? Is the Action.async enough to make myCntr calls asynchronous?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24004444/2292812

Comment: Check out that other question - lots of good information. Can help further if you need but I think that should do it

Comment: Thanks! It did help me! This can be perhaps resolved as duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Action.async` is not enough to make your code asynchronous. Here is the signature for `async` (I picked the simplest overload):

```
def async(block: => Future[Result]): Action[AnyContent]
```

It's up to you to provide that Future. If you're calling blocking code you can execute it concurrently like `Future { blockingCode() }`. However the preferred way is to use futures throughout your application.

A simple action might look something like this:

```
  def lookup(): Future[Connection] = ???
  def query(c: Connection): Future[QueryResult] = ???

  def myCntr = Action.async {
    for {
      conn <- lookup()
      result <- query(conn)
    } yield NoContent
  }
```

Comment: Synchronicity depends more on the underlying DB API here. `Action.async` is just a helper when your methods return `Future`. If you're not using `Action.async`, Play wraps the controller code in `Future` *anyway*. But that does **not** make it truly asynchronous, because a thread is still getting blocked if the underlying API is something like JDBC.

Comment: Right, if you're using JDBC you will have to block. Some databases like MongoDB do offer async APIs, and there are some ongoing efforts to create an async alternative to JDBC.

Comment: @dwickern The example in your answer still blocks the thread because we all use jdbc as golden standard. So what the reason to use this `Action.async` block? You should use wrapper IO monad over your jdbc connection pool (like DBIOAction in Slick 3.0.0)! As for me this answer is more misleading then helpful.