# How async Action api works in play framework 2.2.x for scala?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I was trying to create async api. But the response shows sequential execution. 
Steps done: Open the url in two tabs of chrome. And hit them one after other quickly. url ex:- `localhost:9000/getStar`.

But the execution log is like :-

```
    [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[success] Compiled in 107ms
[info] application - Application has started
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[info] application - Async started ************************** :tarun
[info] application - Success Async call  :1
[info] application - Success Async call  :2
[info] application - Success Async call  :3
[info] application - Success Async call  :4
[info] application - Success Async call  :5
[info] application - Success Async call  :6
[info] application - Success Async call  :7
[info] application - Success Async call  :8
[info] application - Success Async call  :9
[info] application - Async finished ************************** :tarun
[info] application - Async started ************************** :tarun1
[info] application - Success Async call  :1
[info] application - Success Async call  :2
[info] application - Success Async call  :3
[info] application - Success Async call  :4
[info] application - Success Async call  :5
[info] application - Success Async call  :6
[info] application - Success Async call  :7
[info] application - Success Async call  :8
[info] application - Success Async call  :9
[info] application - Async finished ************************** :tarun1
```

The code for this is :

```
package controllers

import play.Logger
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.mvc._


import scala.concurrent.Future

object StarController extends Controller {
  import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext


  def getStarAsync(name : String) = Action.async{
    val futureResult = Future{
      Logger.info("Async started ************************** :" + name)
      val a = 0;
      for( a <- 1 until 10) {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        Logger.info("Success Async call  :" + a.toString)
      }
      Logger.info("Async finished ************************** :" + name)
      Map("success" -> Json.toJson(true), "msg" -> Json.toJson("Success Async by :" + name), "code" -> Json.toJson(200))
    }

    futureResult.map{ result =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(result))
    }
  }

}
```

Can anyone please help me understand , why the execution of the was sequential even with async call ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Action.async` doesn't magically make the controller method asynchronous. The *only* thing it is different about it is that it expects a `Future[Result]` instead of a `Result`. That's it. Controllers are otherwise asynchronous as they can be by nature (i.e. a normal `Action` gets wrapped in a `Future` anyway). The thing here is that `Thread.sleep(1000)` *blocks* it's thread, and is not the least bit asynchronous.

The other thing is that in dev mode (i.e. `activator run`), the play server uses a single thread to serve requests, so it can properly handle reload/compile, evolutions, etc. So what's happening is that you're just blocking that thread with synchronous calls. You should see different results using `activator start`, but even so, there's no point in using `Action.async` here unless you're going to delegate that blocking to a different thread pool.

[Further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997418/are-there-any-benefits-in-using-non-async-actions-in-play-framework-2-2/24004444#24004444) [reading](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ThreadPools).

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot of experiments and found one thing. Maybe it sounds crazy, but Play handles simultaneous requests sequentially only if they are made *from the same browser to the same route*. If I make requests *via curl* or *from different browsers* or even from one browser but *to different routes*, then they are handled asynchronously. Not sure what kind of protection Play does in such a way, but this protection exists and it's a fact.

Comment: I have seen this same behaviour. I am also not able to understand the fact. Thats why it is more confusing to understand the async concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify m-z's answer.
This is example how you could handle some asynchronous collections in your code

```
def getStarAsyncOld(name: String) = Action.async {
  val futureResult = Future {
    Logger.info("Async started ************************** :" + name)
  } flatMap (_ => Future.sequence(for (a <- 1 until 10) yield Future {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    Logger.info("Success Async call  :" + a.toString)
  })) map { _ =>
    Logger.info("Async finished ************************** :" + name)
    Map("success" -> Json.toJson(true), "msg" -> Json.toJson("Success Async by :" + name), "code" -> Json.toJson(200))
  }

  futureResult.map { result =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(result))
  }
}
```

or absolutely the same using `for`:

```
def getStarAsync(name: String) = Action.async {
  for {
    _ <- Future(Logger.info("Async started ************************** :" + name))
    _ <- Future.sequence(for (a <- 1 until 10) yield Future {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      Logger.info("Success Async call  :" + a.toString)
    })
    _ = Logger.info("Async finished ************************** :" + name)
    result = Map("success" -> Json.toJson(true), "msg" -> Json.toJson("Success Async by :" + name), "code" -> Json.toJson(200))
  } yield Ok(Json.toJson(result))
}
```